# Creating object in C++

Tags: c++, oop, object, constructor

I am new to C++. Here's my problem. 
I declare bus, stepper as private instances in the h file:

```
class Motor_control
{
public:
       ...
private:
    IICBus bus ;
    IICStepper stepper ;
    IICStepper stepper_r ;
    IICStepper stepper_l ;
};
```

And then initiate them in the constructor

```
Motor_control::Motor_control(){
    IICBus bus ("/dev/i2c-2",0,"");
    IICStepper stepper (bus,0x00, "Global addr");
    IICStepper stepper_r (bus,0x6e, "Stepper Modul");
    IICStepper stepper_l (bus,0x66, "Stepper Modul");
}
```

IICStepper was declared in .cpp:

```
 IICStepper::IICStepper(IICBus& bus, int addr, const string& name) : IICBase(bus,addr, name) { } in cpp
```

and in .h:

```
class IICStepper : public IICBase { public: IICStepper(IICBus& bus, int addr, const std::string& name); virtual ~IICStepper(){}; ...}
```

It compalins

```
       ../src/Motor_control.h:15: error: no matching function for call to 'IICStepper::IICStepper()'
../src/Stepper.h:41: note: candidates are: IICStepper::IICStepper(IICBus&, int, const std::string&)
../src/Stepper.h:38: note:                 IICStepper::IICStepper(const IICStepper&)
../src/Motor_control.h:15: error: no matching function for call to 'IICBus::IICBus()'
../src/Bus.h:28: note: candidates are: IICBus::IICBus(const std::string&, int, const std::string&)
../src/Bus.h:17: note:                 IICBus::IICBus(const IICBus&)
../src/Motor_control.h:15: error: no matching function for call to 'IICStepper::IICStepper()'
../src/Stepper.h:41: note: candidates are: IICStepper::IICStepper(IICBus&, int, const std::string&)
../src/Stepper.h:38: note:                 IICStepper::IICStepper(const IICStepper&)
../src/Motor_control.h:15: error: no matching function for call to 'IICStepper::IICStepper()'
../src/Stepper.h:41: note: candidates are: IICStepper::IICStepper(IICBus&, int, const std::string&)
../src/Stepper.h:38: note:                 IICStepper::IICStepper(const IICStepper&)
../src/Motor_control.h:15: error: no matching function for call to 'IICStepper::IICStepper()'
../src/Stepper.h:41: note: candidates are: IICStepper::IICStepper(IICBus&, int, const std::string&)
../src/Stepper.h:38: note:                 IICStepper::IICStepper(const IICStepper&)
```

Comment: Please show us line 15 of `Motor_control.h`. That line appears to default-construct an `IICSteppter`, but you don't seem to have a default constructor defined.

Comment: No one gives a correct answer, but there're vote down. Is the question too hard?

Comment: You have received correct answers from myself and Lucian Grigore. The downvote is, I presume, because your question is incomplete. Please reduce your original program to the smallest **complete** program that demonstrates the problem you are having (hint: "smallest" probably means 15 lines or so. "complete" means that I can copy-paste it and compile the result.). For more information about how to produce useful testcases, see http://sscce.org/.

Comment: I have produced a small testcase for you: [this link](http://ideone.com/ryHuY) demonstrates the error, while [think link](http://ideone.com/U9a81) demonstrates the solution.

Answer (score 3):

Before the constructor body enters, all user types are initialized. Because you don't have default constructors for `IICStepper`, you'll get the errors.

You need to use initializer lists:

```
Motor_control::Motor_control() : 
   bus("/dev/i2c-2", 0, ""),
   stepper(bus, 0, "Global addr"),
   stepper_r(bus, 0x6e, "Stepper Modul"),
   stepper_l(bus, 0x66, "Stepper Modul") 
{

}
```

Your version not only doesn't initialize the members, it creates new temporary objects which you never use afterwards.

Comment: @KevinQ then that's not the code that's causing the problem. Please post relevant code - with copy paste.

Comment: @KevinQ why before the edit you had &bus? Are you copy-pasting the code? If not, please do so.

Answer (score 0):

My best guess here is that when you pass a string as an argument, such as

```
"Global addr"
```

, the string is passed as a 'const char*', not a 'const std::string&'. You're simply passing the wrong type of variable, from my perspective.

Comment: std::string has a conversion constructor from const char*, that's not a problem.

Answer (score 0):

This is wrong:

```
Motor_control::Motor_control(){
    IICBus bus ("/dev/i2c-2",0,"");
    IICStepper stepper (bus,0x00, "Global addr");
    IICStepper stepper_r (bus,0x6e, "Stepper Modul");
    IICStepper stepper_l (bus,0x66, "Stepper Modul");
}
```

The above code doesn't do what you think it does. Specifically, it creates three local variables (local to the constructor function) whose names are coincidentally identical to the names of three *other* variables -- your member variables. This code does **not** initialize your member variables.

The error messages you see are caused by the default initialization of your member variables. To avoid default initialization, you must list your member variables in an initializer list, like this:

```
Motor_control::Motor_control() : bus("/dev/i2c-2", 0, ""),
    stepper(bus, 0, "Global addr"),
    stepper_r(bus, 0x6e, "Stepper Modul"),
    stepper_l(bus, 0x66, "Stepper Modul") {
}
```

Comment: I do intend to create some global instances to be used by other function in this motor_control class. Your suggestion didn't resolve the problem. It gives still the same error.

Comment: If the first line of this fragment is line 15 of motor_control.h, then I'm certain the compiler doesn't give the same error. It may give another error, but it is surely not the same.

Comment: First and remaining three? You list five errors in your question.